# html button component not highlighting

Tags: html, jsp

When i navigate through **Tab key** in my jsp. **button** in my page are not getting highlighting (i.e it doesnot focus on buttons with dotted line). but it focus on checkbox and radio button.  As i am not allowed to change to **input type="button" or button**. what is the use of **aria-disabled="false" ?**

```
     <body>
  <a href="javascript:submitForm('reset');" class="ui-button-default ui-button ui-widget  ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="ui-text-only">RESET</span></a>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put this attribute:

tabindex="K", where "k" is the number of how many times You have to press the TAB key to highlight that link.

Comment: it is difficult to count as it is dynamic page. components are added dynamically.